# Pullback of a translation map of a divisor in Birkenhake-Lange's book "Complex Abelian Varieties"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm currently studying the book 'Complex Abelian Varieties' by Birkenhake and Lange. On page 74, after lemma 1.5, the authors make the following statement:

'Another observation, which will prove useful on multiple occasions, is as follows: by definition, $t_x^*D = D - x$, which implies that $y \in t_x^*D$ if and only if $x \in t_y^*D$.

However, I'm having trouble understanding the equation $t_x^*D = D - x$. For instance, if we take $D = \sum n_p(p)$, it seems to me that the pullback of a translation by $-x$ of the divisor should be $D = \sum n_p(p-x)$. Can someone clarify this for me?"

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The support of the pullback of a Cartier divisor equals the inverse image of the support.  The inverse image of a subset $D$ under $t_x$ is $\{y\in A : x+y\in D\} = \{y\in A : y \in D-x\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the welcome. However, I still don't understand. In B-L's book, a divisor is defined as the "zero-set" of a section $\sigma$ of a line bundle $L$ (a set, not the formal sum as usual... why?).

Naturally, $t_x^* D$ might be defined as the zero-set of $t_x^* \sigma$. If we think of $D$ as a formal sum $D = \sum n_p(p)$, then naturally $t_x^* D = \sum n_p(p-x)$.

It seems like you are equating divisor $D$ with its support $Supp(D)$. Then, does $D-x$ mean $Supp(D) - {x}$ instead of $D-x = \sum n_p(p-x)$ in your answer?

Comment: Are you considering elliptic curves? A divisor is a linear combination of hypersurfaces, not of points.

Comment: Thank you, abx. I had unconsciously been considering a divisor as a formal sum of points rather than codimension one subvarieties. However, this made the notation in B-H appear more confusing to me. By defining $D=\sum n_V(V)$ with $V$ as codimension one subvarieties, I expect that $t_x^*D$ would be composed of translated subvarieties and valuations of the original ones by $x$. Then, I am not sure what the equality $t_x^*D = D-x$ means exactly. Is it just a definition of the notation like $D-x := t_x^*D$? In that case  Does $y \in t_x^*D$ mean that the point $y$ belongs to a subvariety of $D$?

Comment: Ok, I conclude that the last conjecture is correct.. maybe. Since I saw the similar definition in an old paper about Abelian varieties. That might be just a notation.